# Probability and Expected Value of the Minimum Sample from Multiple Gaussians

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Suppose we sample from $d$ independent Gaussians with different means, denoted by $\mu_1, \mu_2, ... ,\mu_d$, such that the means are ordered with $\mu_1 < \mu_2, ... <\mu_d$. All of the Gaussians have the same variance. What is the probability that the sample coming from the $a$'th Gaussian (mean $\mu_a$) is the minimum among the samples drawn from all $d$ Gaussians? And what is its expected value when it is the minimum among the samples? I think I've solved this and I just want to make sure I didn't make an error.

My first goal is to find $P(X_a < \min(\{X_i\}_{i\neq a}))$. Let $X_m$ be this minimum. Is it correct to say that:

$P(X_a < X_m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_a}(x)P(X_m > x)dx$

If so, then we can proceed as follows: $P(X_m > x) = \prod_{i\neq a} P(X_i > x)= \prod_{i\neq a} (1 - F_{X_i}(x))$. Then we just need to evaluate the following integral:

$$P(X_a < X_m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_a}(x)\prod_{i\neq a} (1 - F_{X_i}(x))dx$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_a}(x)\prod_{i\neq a} (1 - \Phi(\frac{x-\mu_i}{\sigma}))dx$$
Where $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF of a standard normal variable. There are tools to evaluate this integral.

Now I want to find $\mathbb E(X_a|X_a < X_m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X_a|X_a < X_m}(x)$. I am not sure how to find the density $f_{X_a|X_a < X_m}(x)$. By the definition of conditional probability, $f_{X|Y}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$, so maybe the density I need is this:

$$f_{X_a|X_a < X_m}(x) = \frac{f_{X_a}(x)P(X_m > x)}{P(X_a < X_m)}$$

If this is right, then the expectation is just:

$$\mathbb E(X_a|X_a < X_m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xf_{X_a}(x)P(X_m > x)}{P(X_a < X_m)}dx$$

$$= \frac{1}{P(X_a < X_m)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X_a}(x)P(X_m > x)dx$$

Are there any issues with this line of reasoning, or is everything correct?

Comment: In general, if $f$ is the density of the random vector $(A,B),$ then $P(A < B) = \int_R f,$ where $R$ is the region of $\mathbf{R}^2$ defined by $x < y.$ Tonelli's theorem also shows $\int_R f(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \int_{-\infty}^y dx f(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_x^\infty dy f(x,y).$